# Spring boot "Request method 'POST' not supported"

Tags: java, spring

```
@Controller
public class ControllerClass {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String test(){
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

It's a simple mvc controller class where I post request to get index.html page in resource/static folder. Whenever I send the post request from rest client or from html forms, I get the error - "Request method 'POST' not supported". 
When I change to "RequestMethod.POST" to "RequestMethod.GET" it worked properly.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't sending any request body?

Comment: you should be able to remove that controller and the GET will still work.  spring boot automatically serves static content from /resource/static as well as a couple other locations: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot.  it doesn't really make sense to POST to get a static html file, do you have to POST?

Comment: Also `@RestController` is more appropriate where you have methods whose return values are expected to form the HTTP response body. As a simple test, add `@ResponseBody` to your `test()` method.

Comment: Have you enabled CSRF? if yes, then you need to send csrf token.

Comment: CSRF is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding thymeleaf stater dependency in pom.xml and moved all the html file from static folder to template folder.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Ideally it should work without thymeleaf but I don't get why it doesn't support for POST requests.